# Use big landspace pictures for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and etc

Tags: android

I have 100 background pictures for my app.
Now I want to use the same pictures with the same resolution for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and etc.

If I put the all pictures in xhdpi folder, for example, it will be ok for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi ?
I just don't want to resize the pictures for all folders.

The pictures are for landspace background. Does they will appear right and fully on the screen ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They will, but that means that a small screen device should also show a 4Mb picture on its screen. If it's an old phone, then it will probably crash because its memory got exhausted, but even if it doesn't, it will have a slow UI.

There are automated tools for properly resizing images, I recommend [9-Patch-Resizer](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer). You can drag-and-drop all your 100 images, and it will resize them ordered into the correct dimension folders.